# Add Admob smart without overlapping content

Tags: javascript, android, admob

I have my smart banner working, but Google AdMob ad serving has been disabled to my application

Violation explanation 
ADS AND CONTENT OVERLAP: As stated in our program policies, publishers are not permitted to alter the behavior of AdMob ads in any way. This includes placing ads so that they cover any part of the application content or parts of an application covering any portion of the ads. If your app has drop-down menus they are not permitted to cover AdMob ads.....

Appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

`MainActivity.java`

```js
package bb.hoppingbird;

import org.cocos2d.layers.CCScene;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector;
import org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CCGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

    //<!-- Admob Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1141613635835332/7968365003";
    private static final String AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID = "df2cce209f194168";


    /** The Admob ad. */
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;
    public AdView adView = null;

    public static MainActivity app;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        app = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set view
        mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);


        //Ads ----------------
        // Create the adView
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        //<!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Add the adView to it
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        adView.setLayoutParams(params);

        layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
        layout.addView(adView);

        setContentView(layout);
        //New AdRequest 
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //-----------------------------------------------------Interstitial Add
        // Create an Interstitial ad.
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
              @Override
              public void onAdLoaded() {
                interstitialAd.show();
              }

              @Override
              public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interstitial Ads loading failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        });
         // Load the interstitial ad.
        //showInterstitialAds();

        //----------------------
        // set director
        CCDirector director = CCDirector.sharedDirector();
        director.attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);
        director.setAnimationInterval(1/60);

        // get display info
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        G.display_w = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        G.display_h = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        G.scale = Math.max(G.display_w/1280.0f, G.display_h/800.0f);
        G.width = G.display_w / G.scale;
        G.height = G.display_h / G.scale;

        // get data
        SharedPreferences sp = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GameInfo", 0);
        G.music = sp.getBoolean("music", true);
        G.sound = sp.getBoolean("sound", true);

        // create sound
        G.soundMenu = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
        G.soundMenu.setLooping(true);
        G.soundGame = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.game);
        G.soundGame.setLooping(true);
        G.soundCollide = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collide);
        G.soundJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jump);
        G.soundLongJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.long_jump);
        G.soundSpeedDown = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_down);
        G.soundSpeedUp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_up);
        G.soundDirection = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.direction_sign);
        G.soundClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu_click);
        G.soundCollect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collect);
        G.bgSound = G.soundMenu;

        // show menu
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
        scene.addChild(new MenuLayer(true));
        director.runWithScene(scene);
    }  

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        if (adView != null) {
              adView.pause();
            }

        super.onPause();
        G.bgSound.pause();
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
          }

        if( G.music ) G.bgSound.start();

        CCDirector.sharedDirector().onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
        G.bgSound.pause();
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().onKeyDown(event);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void showInterstitialAds()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 AdRequest interstitialAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                 interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialAdRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your app? By the way, it would be great if you can also add your layout xml.